# Side table design: will wood movement and expansion be an issue?

Tags: design, wood-movement

I'm a beginning woodworker, and I've made a design for a side table. It's a small table, measuring 400x350mm (~ 16x14 inches). I'd like to make it in two types of wood, for the legs and the top. I was thinking about orienting the grain such that it runs vertically for the legs, and horizontally for the connecting leg pieces.

I was planning on just gluing the leg frame to the top, optionally with some structural reinforcement such a dominos or dowels. But I'm worried a bit that wood movement and expansion will be an issue, especially if I'm using two species of wood.

Will will movement be an issue with this design? And if so, what would be the best way to deal with it? Would orienting or matching the grain direction a certain way be enough?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Aesthetically I wanted to compliment you on the design, this is very nice IMO. But, you're a beginner woodworker? You're asking a very good question here, but that you're having to ask it at all suggests to me that you're not ready to build it — the wood-movement issue between the legs and the top is either a complete non-issue, or can easily be accounted for (i.e. the grain direction of the top is irrelevant). So there are other more pressing issues! Any one of them might derail this build. The focus of the Q is about the leg-to-top joint and that's what we [contd]

Comment: ...should focus on for you, but there are other aspects of the design that inevitably will come under scrutiny. And given that you haven't yet groked wood movement I suspect you either haven't thought them through fully or you're biting off more than you can chew. Those leg structures wouldn't be at all straightforward to implement for some advanced leisure woodworkers, and even some pros.

Comment: Agree with answers that this is a really tough project. As drawn, it’s unlikely to hold up to normal use. Think about table aprons and how those function — perhaps a surreptitious X under the tabletop would suffice. Also suggest you take the comment about lower stability seriously: traditional chair legs have stretchers for a reason. (Chairs without stretchers have much beefier legs and aprons.)

Comment: I think you're both right, this is probably too difficult a project to start with. I'm fully expecting it to not turn out 100% the way I designed it, but I like to just try and see how far I will get. In the very least there will be some interesting techniques for me to try out and learn :).

Comment: Late as usual... I love your spunk, @Rengers, but would caution you that trying to bite off an advanced project as a beginner could well go south on you. You might just end up too frustrated with the process and decide that woodworking isn't for you because you fail at this one. Of course, you know you, but do keep that in mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are gluing everything together, different types of wood should work just fine provided that top is solid wood and the wood grain on the top and the horizontals are in the same direction (that way each piece of wood expands and contracts at the same rate).

However, there are a number of considerations you should incorporate into your final design:

- Your leg structure looks more like a metal design than wood.  The curved corners might be achievable using a laminate/plywood material, but will not be easy to construct from solid materials (nor, possibly, as strong). Keep in mind that the leg assembly on each side must resist racking from front to back as well as side to side and you are putting complex joint assemblies at the place where the ability of the assembly to resist shifting from square is most pronounced. Such joints are certainly possible, but are more complex that a simple butt joint.
- The legs are not cross braced in any way except at the top and this connection lacks an apron to provide support against racking. All the lateral force is transferred through the fastening between the top and horizontal leg members and it may not be enough if an unplanned force is applied the table.  If you screw the top to the horizontals, there will be strong tendency for the screw to pull out of the top.  Gluing the legs and top together will handle the stress much better.
- If you drag the table along a floor, the legs assemblies on each side will be pulled independently and are more likely to skew a bit and at different angles.  If you look at typical wood table design there is often a lower open shelf.  This provides additional bracing to keep the legs at the same width and square at the bottom.

Comment: For the curved corners I'm planning to use a template and router. I am indeed worried about racking and skewing, and in that sense I think this is not a perfect design in its current state. I'm still thinking about how to counteract that, while still staying true to this "minimalist" design.

Comment: @Rengers, just in case it's helpful, did you realise the difficulty in forming those corners from solid wood? This sort of thing is a notoriously difficult thing to implement successfully in wood because of the 90° swing in the desired strength axes. And additionally it results in the need to make two near-perfect reinforced joints *per corner* to link them to the uprights and the horizontal 'foot'.

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking about orienting the grain such that it runs vertically for the legs, and horizontally for the connecting leg pieces.

It *has to* be done this way, this is just the way you build any rectilinear structure in wood. Ignore the round corners for the moment, you're just building something similar to a picture frame, or the perimeter of a frame-and-panel, sans panel.

> I was planning on just gluing the leg frame to the top, optionally with some structural reinforcement such a Dominos or dowels.

That could work, and wouldn't require reinforcement since as we know glue joints can be stronger than the wood itself...... saving the very relevant concern about how you'd do Dominos as a beginner! ^_^

But, whether you can/should glue depends on an aspect of the design that you haven't addressed in the Q, one which is the elephant in the room: **which way is the grain oriented in the top?**

(We've learned through experience not to go by the apparent grain direction in a render, because sometimes that's assigned arbitrarily and actually the intent is for it to be 90° to what's shown.)

> But I'm worried a bit that wood movement and expansion will be an issue, especially if I'm using two species of wood.

The key issue here wouldn't be that there are two species involved, *that's actually a non-issue either way* — with one grain orientation of the top wood movement is irrelevant, for the other you just need to allow for it<sup>1</sup>.

So, in short, what you've asked about here is the least of your worries!

This is an ambitious design to say the least and while every issue I foresee (which may not be all of them!) is conquerable in one or more ways, actually building this successfully at your current level will I suspect be a mountain you can't yet climb.

**An easier, and possibly not more expensive alternative**
If instead of building the leg structures from wood they were made from metal<sup>2</sup> all concerns basically go away. But note that I think this forces the choice of grain orientation for the top, and you have to be able to live with fasteners being visible on the outward face of the legs.

---

<sup>1</sup> In much the same way we allow for relative movement of the tabletop and the stiles of a standard table's apron.

<sup>2</sup> Aluminium or steel, but brass could maybe work although might be cost-prohibitive. For a number of reasons I think steel would be preferable here: easiest to find a fabricator, possibly cheapest and likely the strongest even if hollow-section material (square tubing) is used.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer!

Ideally the top grain would be oriented perpendicular to the grain of the horizontal top leg piece, so that it would be covered by the miter and not visible from the side. 

Metal would definitely be better, I agree, but unfortunately I don't have access to a metal workshop (nor any metal working skills)

Comment: Re. metal, I should have worded this differently in the Answer: I meant to have it fabricated for you — and even with that it was my suspicion that they could work out equivalent or cheaper than the proposed wooden legs O_O (Based on my assumption that certain purchases would have to be made in terms of tools, and possibly one or two items built, to successfully pull off the fabrication of the wooden components.)

Comment: @Rengers consider buying a set of standard, manufactured legs. It would be perfectly acceptable for a first project to use some "help" that way. Heck a lot of _advanced_ woodworkers will chose to use purchased metal legs simply because they want to.